# HtmlGenericControl("td") colspan

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net c# so please anyone can help me with below code:

```
var td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
```

How can I make this td colspan to anyvalue?

Even how can I add id or class value?

Comment: dknaack's answer is the correct one. However, the *normal* way to do this is through HTML/ASP.NET markup and not by creating your elements this way. What you are doing is valid if needed, but since you said you are new, I would recommend you review why you need this in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add it to the `HtmlGenericControl.Attributes` collection

> **HtmlControl.Attributes Property** Gets a collection of all attribute name and value pairs expressed on a server control tag within the ASP.NET page.

#### Sample

```
var td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
td1.Attributes.Add("colspan", "1"); // replace "1" with the correct value.
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - HtmlControl.Attributes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes.aspx)
- [MSDN - AttributeCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.aspx)

Comment: If you dont mind can you reply me for this..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182521/add-controls-dynamically-to-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

To add a `td` control to the page, have markup(.aspx) that could look like this

```
<table><tr id="row" runat="server"></tr></table>
```

Then to add `td1` to the page have this in your code behind:

```
row.Controls.add(td1);
```

Then to set the `colspan` attribute either use the method by dknaack:

```
td1.Attributes.Add("colspan", 1);
```

or you could do it in markup as:

```
<td colspan="<%= ValueOfColSpanProperty %>">TableCell</td>
```

---

To set the class

```
td1.Attributes.Add("class", "tablecell");
```

To set the id set the `ID` property:

```
td1.ID = "id1";
```

To control how the ID gets rendered on the client use the `ClientIDMode` property if avaliable:

```
td1.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.AutoID;
```

Answer (score -2):

HtmlGenericControl is generally using for div.
You should use HtmlTableCell.

```
HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell();
td.ColSpan = 2;
```

Comment: I think the `HtmlGenericControl` is not only for a div tag. It can represent any html element.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I edit my comment, but I think the best way is using HtmlTableCell for td.