# How to change colspan of a td dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

```
  <FooterTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color:Orange;">
    < td width="6%" align="center" id = "tdFooter" runat = "server" colspan = "3">                                   
    </td>
</tr>
</FooterTemplate>
```

I have a repeater control in which i have this footer template. All i want is to change the colspan of tdFooter at itemdatabound event(c#) on the basis of some if clauses.How can i do the same?

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
{
    if(role = 0)
       {
         //tdfooter colspan should be 3
       }
else
      {
        //tdfoote colspan should be 2
      }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would add a runat to the td tag

```
<td runat="server" id="tdControl">
```

in the itemdatabound:

```
 var td = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdControl");
 td.Attributes.Add("colspan", myNumber);
```

Comment: Also, I just found more or less the same thing answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241698/htmlgenericcontroltd-colspan

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but instead of (HtmlGenericControl) it should be (HtmlTableCell) and now its working :)